# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'fields' Using Django non rel on GAE

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

I'm doing an app with Django non rel on Google App Engine, and im using Bootstrap...to use Bootstrap on Django Forms i installed django_forms_bootstrap (https://github.com/pinax/django-forms-bootstrap)

The thing is...when i deploy on GAE and trying to create a new user (registration) i get the Server Error (500), but the new user is created...the log of GAE show this:

```
> Exception in request: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/base/data/home/apps/s~softsystemanager/1.378394621720949564/django/core/handlers/base.py",
> line 113, in get_response
>     response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   File
> "/base/data/home/apps/s~softsystemanager/1.378394621720949564/myapp/modulos/presentacion/views.py",
> line 32, in signup_view
>     return render_to_response('presentacion/login.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))   File
> "/base/data/home/apps/s~softsystemanager/1.378394621720949564/django/shortcuts/__init__.py",
> line 29, in render_to_response
>     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs), **httpresponse_kwargs)   File "/base/data/home/apps/s~softsystemanager/1.378394621720949564/django/template/loader.py",
> line 177, in render_to_string
>     return t.render(context_instance)   File "/base/data/home/apps/s~softsystemanager/1.378394621720949564/django/template/base.py",
> line 140, in render
>     return self._render(context)   File "/base/data/home/apps/s~softsystemanager/1.378394621720949564/django/template/base.py",
> line 134, in _render
>     return self.nodelist.render(context)   File "/base/data/home/apps/s~softsystemanager/1.378394621720949564/django/template/base.py",
> line 830, in render
>     bit = self.render_node(node, context)   File "/base/data/home/apps/s~softsystemanager/1.378394621720949564/django/template/base.py",
> line 844, in render_node
>     return node.render(context)   File "/base/data/home/apps/s~softsystemanager/1.378394621720949564/django/template/loader_tags.py",
> line 124, in render
>     return compiled_parent._render(context)   File "/base/data/home/apps/s~softsystemanager/1.378394621720949564/django/template/base.py",
> line 134, in _render
>     return self.nodelist.render(context)   File "/base/data/home/apps/s~softsystemanager/1.378394621720949564/django/template/base.py",
> line 830, in render
>     bit = self.render_node(node, context)   File "/base/data/home/apps/s~softsystemanager/1.378394621720949564/django/template/base.py",
> line 844, in render_node
>     return node.render(context)   File "/base/data/home/apps/s~softsystemanager/1.378394621720949564/django/template/loader_tags.py",
> line 63, in render
>     result = block.nodelist.render(context)   File "/base/data/home/apps/s~softsystemanager/1.378394621720949564/django/template/base.py",
> line 830, in render
>     bit = self.render_node(node, context)   File "/base/data/home/apps/s~softsystemanager/1.378394621720949564/django/template/base.py",
> line 844, in render_node
>     return node.render(context)   File "/base/data/home/apps/s~softsystemanager/1.378394621720949564/django/template/base.py",
> line 881, in render
>     output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)   File "/base/data/home/apps/s~softsystemanager/1.378394621720949564/django/template/base.py",
> line 606, in resolve
>     new_obj = func(obj, *arg_vals)   File "/base/data/home/apps/s~softsystemanager/1.378394621720949564/django_forms_bootstrap/templatetags/bootstrap_tags.py",
> line 20, in as_bootstrap
>     form = _preprocess_fields(form)   File "/base/data/home/apps/s~softsystemanager/1.378394621720949564/django_forms_bootstrap/templatetags/bootstrap_tags.py",
> **line 10, in _preprocess_fields
>     for field in form.fields: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'fields'**
```

Then i go to the file bootstrap_tags.py and i see no error

```
> def _preprocess_fields(form):
>     for field in form.fields:
>         name = form.fields[field].widget.__class__.__name__.lower()
>         if not name.startswith("radio") and not name.startswith("checkbox"):
>             form.fields[field].widget.attrs["class"] = " form-control"
>     return form
> 
> 
> @register.filter def as_bootstrap(form):
>     template = get_template("bootstrap/form.html")
>     form = _preprocess_fields(form)
> 
>     c = Context({
>         "form": form,
>     })
>     return template.render(c)
```

In the HTML file of my app i got this

```
<div class="col-md-4 ">
            <form action="." method="POST">
                {%csrf_token%}
                {{ form|as_bootstrap}}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign UP</button>
            </form>     
        </div>
    </div>
```

and i don't know if this is useful but here is the form

```
class RegisterForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label="Nombre de Usuario",widget=forms.TextInput())
    name = forms.CharField(label="Nombre",widget=forms.TextInput())
    last_name = forms.CharField(label="Apellido",widget=forms.TextInput())
    email = forms.EmailField(label="Correo Electronico", widget=forms.TextInput())
    password_one = forms.CharField(label="Password", widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False))
    password_two = forms.CharField(label="Confirmar Password", widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False))
```

In fact, the error is with this particular form, because i have another one, the login form, and it works perfectly and im using the same procedure to use the django_forms_bootstrap

The source code of my singup_view is:

```
def signup_view(request):
    form = RegisterForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            password_one = form.cleaned_data['password_one']
            password_two = form.cleaned_data['password_two']
            newUser = User.objects.create_user(username=username, first_name=name, last_name=last_name, email=email, password=password_one)
            newUser.save()
            return render_to_response('presentacion/login.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        else:
            ctx = {'form':form}
            return render_to_response('presentacion/sign_up.html',ctx, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    ctx = {'form':form}
    return render_to_response('presentacion/sign_up.html',ctx, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Please Help!!!

Comment: Please post the code for your `signup_view` method.

Comment: The problem is with your `login.html` file, not your `sign_up.html` file. In your `login.html` file, do you have a `{{ form|as_bootstrap }}`?

Comment: Yes, what should i do??

Comment: @BurhanKhalid i think i solved it i changed:

return render_to_response('presentacion/login.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))

for:

return HttpResponseRedirect('/login')

it works!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `login.html` template, you have `{{ form|as_bootstrap }}`, but in your code for signing up, you are rendering the template for login, but you are not passing in the form value:

```
return render_to_response('presentacion/login.html',
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

There is no context here.

You need to fix this by redirecting the user to the login *view*, instead of rendering the login *template* from your sign up view.

In addition, you should use the [`render` shortcut](http://django.me/render) which will automatically send `RequestContext`.

Your are also not checking for duplicate users.

To fix these issues in your code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

def signup_view(request):
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None)
    ctx = {'form': form}
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            password_one = form.cleaned_data['password_one']
            password_two = form.cleaned_data['password_two']
            if not User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                 newUser = User.objects.create_user(username=username,
                                                    first_name=name,
                                                    last_name=last_name,
                                                    email=email,
                                                    password=password_one)
                 newUser.save()
            else:
                 # Do something, because a user
                 # with this email already exists
                 pass
            return redirect('login')

    return render(request, 'presentacion/sign_up.html', ctx)
```

Answer (score 7):

If you ended up here like me with a similar error, in Django 2.2.4, using `as_table|crispy` doesn't seem to work at all. The solution was to remove `as_table`:

*Before*

```
<div class="col-md-4 ">
   <form action="." method="POST">
         {%csrf_token%}
         {{ form.as_table|as_bootstrap}}
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign UP</button>
    </form>     
</div>
```

*After*

```
<div class="col-md-4 ">
   <form action="." method="POST">
         {%csrf_token%}
         {{ form|as_bootstrap}}
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign UP</button>
    </form>     
</div>
```

This may not answer the OP's question, but if you ended up here like me, hope this helps you.

Comment: My issue was with `{form.as_p|crispy}}` - removing `as_p` similarly got rid of the error